# RFID reader technology

Tags: rf, antenna, rfid, antenna-array

Hopefully this isn't too broad of a question, I will narrow it down the best I can.

We need to add RFID tags to feeders on our pick and place machine, to determine that they are loaded into the correct position on the machine itself. Other than having a reader for every single slot, that only reads a single feeders RFID tag, what are my options?

I could have a single reader with longer range, but since the tags we will use will be passive, location tracking will not be overly accurate. I looked into phased array antennas, but they seem still experimental..

If we used a single RFID reader for each feeder slot, that would require over 100 readers..

I'm open to other technologies other than RFID, but I presume that it is the obvious choice.

Comment: have you thought of using barcode readers?

Comment: maybe the pick and place head can carry a sensor along the line of feeders to identify them.  if it already has a camera QR codes might be an easier solution.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, that has been our original idea. But it either requires a operator to manually scan, or a upwards facing camera. The former still has operator error and the latter isn't overly elegant, and can have missreads

Comment: @Jasen Another idea we had, but unfortunately we can't adjust the software in the pick and place at all, so I don't know what procedure we could have it do to check all parts. And it has 8 heads, so it doesn't always go to the exact same spot to pick

Comment: you could use a scanner module in a similar way as an rfid module .... no human operator required

Comment: @jsotola How so? Have a camera positioned as to be able to read all the barcodes? Then software would determine where they are?

Comment: one barcode scanner in each bin position

Comment: @jsotola Yeah? Got an example of a scanner that is small enough, and able to be interfaced with over 100 of them?

Comment: one problem with RFID is low spatial precision with normal antennas, most antennas cover a volume of about 1 litre, that's too big for you average feeder.  why do you presume it's the obvious choice? what features of RFID do you like?

Comment: @Jasen Mainly because that's what is the industry standard for current Gen "smart" feeders. We have older Gem series Phillips /assembleon machines with Yamaha CL feeders

Comment: A no-brand USB 13.56MHZ RFID reader can cost as low as 5€. I think if you need to design your own with some specific industrial interface, you can make it almost as cheap using specific chips like ST25R95, CR95HF, ... So, what's wrong with having one reader per slot? I'm having hard time imagining cheaper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.circuitnet.com/experts/39998.html  juki uses an array of antennas (presumably one per slot)  perhaps wired in a matrix like this.

the antennas could perhaops be drum inductors (they's haver to be something with a small field so as to be sufficiently selective to only see one tag)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5I09s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>